# How to compile Numa library?

Tags: numa

How should I compile the numa source code(ftp://oss.sgi.com/www/projects/libnuma/download/numactl-2.0.10.tar.gz) to get the libnuma.so, both for 32bit and 64bit?

Comment: There is one autogen.sh file in the package, I use "./autogen.sh && ./configure && make " to generate the library, but only 64bit library is generated, how can I generate the 32bit library?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compile-32bit-application-using-gcc-64-bit-linux.html

Comment: Hi Proghero, thanks very much for your help! I have add '-m32' for CFLAGS then can make the 32bit library. On Centos5, I also upgrade autoconf, automake, libtool, now I can get what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Shaohua, you're welcome! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
$ tar xfzv numactl-2.0.10.tar.gz
$ cd numactl-2.0.10
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

(Based on the instructions in the file INSTALL inside the link above)

Comment: Hi Proghero, there is no Makefile in the numactl-2.0.10, so I can not try this.

Comment: Hi @Shaohua, I updated my answer. Take a look at the file called INSTALL. You have to run a script before. I hope it helps!